# Selecting tables based on multiple values in a cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have something that looks like this:

```
if ( $_SESSION['username'] ) 
        $owner = $_SESSION['username'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM projects where owners='$owner' ORDER BY created DESC";
```

The problem is that the 'owners' column may have multiple entries separated by commas. I need a way to cycle through all the entries and select any table that has $owner in the owners columns. Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean with cell? You've a multivalued column? Owner column has multiple values?

Comment: You've made **wrong** design decision. Instead of storing multiple values in a *single cell* - you'd better had it moved to *separated table*.

Comment: Sorry, when I said cell, I meant column.

Comment: @zerkms How would moving the owners to a different table help? Wouldn't I just end up putting multiple entries in to a single column on a different table?

Comment: @Thomas: no - you would have N lines per project according to the number of owners. So each owner would be a separate row: `1 a`, `1 b`, `1 c` <-- the sample of 3 owners of project id = 1

Comment: @zerkms So with this setup, I would have potentially unlimited tables on my database - is there a way to organize the tables into a group? Should I use a separate database altogether?

Comment: @Thomas: I can't get what you mean. With this setup you'll have 1 table for projects and 1 table for owners. That's it, just 2 tables.

Comment: See my answer to [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for sharing this, I now understand why this is a bad design decision, however, I am still having trouble wrapping my mind around how to structure this. Are there any other resources you could point me to? I'd google it but Im not exactly sure what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper design for a relational database is to store only one value in a given "cell" (i.e. in a given column on a given row -- but please do not use spreadsheet terminology with relational databases, you'll make [Joe Celko](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887975) cry.  :-).

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects (
 project_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 ...
);

CREATE TABLE Users (
 user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 ...
);

CREATE TABLE Project_Owners (
  project_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (project_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Projects(project_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
);
```

You insert one row to Project_Owners table for each owner of a given project.  So you can easily have a project with multiple owners, and a user who works on multiple projects.

We say that Projects has a *many-to-many* relationship to Users.

So when you want to get projects associated with a given owner, you'd need to look up the owner in the users table, and then join that to projects via the many-to-many table:

```
<?php

$owner = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["username"]);

$sql = "SELECT p.* FROM Projects
INNER JOIN Project_Owners o USING (project_id)
INNER JOIN Users u USING (user_id)
WHERE u.name = '$owner'";
```

Or if you want to simplify it, you can use integers in your session data. Then you can skip a join:

```
<?php

$owner = (int) $_SESSION["username"];

$sql = "SELECT p.* FROM Projects
INNER JOIN Project_Owners o USING (project_id)
WHERE o.user_id = $owner";
```

The concept of storing just one value in a cell is part of the basic definition of [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  Any book on SQL should cover this, even the [Manga Guide to Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271905).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for taking the time to lay it out!